# Can a Paladin use his Mercies with Channel Positive Energy?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, paladin

Anyone that gets a Lay on hands from a Paladin also gets all the effects of the Paladin's Mercies. As the Channel Positive Energy uses two lay on hands do they also get the effects of the Mercies?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**NO.**

Quote from [Pathfinder SRD](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/paladin#TOC-Channel-Positive-Energy-Su-):

> Whenever the paladin uses lay on hands to heal damage to one target, the target also receives the additional effects from all of the mercies possessed by the paladin.

Using *lay on hands* to *channel energy* is clearly not the case.

Comment: Agreed, and as a broader rule, using resource X, normally used for Y, to do Z, is still not doing Y, and therefore doesn't qualify for bonuses/penalties associated with doing Y.

Comment: @Melon Even broader, anything that says, "The rules say I can do Thing X, does that mean I can also do (largely unrelated) Thing Y?", the answer is always "No." Possible duplicates: half the questions on this site.